# Couldn't Get lock while logging with Tomcat6 and Servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets, logging

I want to log RequestHeaders in a logfile. I did the following:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");

    public TestServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler("logfile.txt", true);
        logger.addHandler(fileHandler);

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String title = "Request Headers";
        out.println("<HTML>" +
                    "<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FDF5E6\">\n" +
                    "<H1 ALIGN=CENTER>" + title + "</H1>\n" +
                    "<B>Request Method: </B>" +
                    request.getMethod() + "<BR>\n" +
                    "<B>Request URI: </B>" +
                    request.getRequestURI() + "<BR>\n" +
                    "<B>Request Protocol: </B>" +
                    request.getProtocol() + "<BR><BR>\n" +
                    "<TABLE BORDER=1 ALIGN=CENTER>\n" +
                    "<TR BGCOLOR=\"#DGAD00\">\n" +
                    "<TH>Header Name<TH>Header Value");

        Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();

        while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
          String headerName = (String)headerNames.nextElement();
          out.println("<TR><TD>" + headerName);
          out.println("    <TD>" + request.getHeader(headerName));
        }
        out.println("</TABLE>\n</BODY></HTML>");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

I get the following exception:
java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for logfile.txt

I am using Tomcat6.0.32 and java.util.logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach of adding a logger is wrong.

I bet the first time called after the application is deployed, this works; from the second time on it fails. Why? Because each time `logger.addHandler(fileHandler)` gets called, another handler is appended. So the second time 2 handlers will try to write to the logfile; the 3rd time three; and so on. Fortunately the handler tries to lock the file, so the first succeeds while the ones after it fail with the exception. If the lock exception wasnt thrown, you would be seing messages like this:

```
1st time
2nd time
2nd time
3rd time
3rd time
3rd time
```

...and so on.

There is also the chance that you don't have permissions to write to the `logfile.txt`.

Anyway, the solution is to add the handler once in the appropriate configuration file.

If you want the headers to be logged in a separate file, create a category specific to your needs, attach the `FileHandler` to this category and, in your servlet log in a separate logger, e.g.:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");
private static Logger headersLogger = Logger.getLogger("headersLogger");
```

Comment: If i add the absolut path, it works! And you are wrong: It doesn't work right after the deployment, but your explanation sounded good.

Comment: It is strange that it works... In any case this is not the correct way to add a handler. If it is a temporary patch for debugging, do it at least in the servlet's `init()` method.

Comment: I will try to follow your suggestion above. What now happens is the following: Every time i send a GET Request, a new lock gets created (as you mentioned). I want to write every GET Request in a single logfile.

Comment: You mean every request in a single file *AND different* than the previous? If so I'd suggest you created a custom subclass of `FileHandler` that implements this behaviour (and add it to the configuration properly :-)

Comment: Sorry, i mean every Request in one and the same file.

Comment: Ok, i moved the initialization of the FileHanlder to the constructor. Now everything works just fine.